# AVPlayerViewController not working on iOS17

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit, ios17

My app shows a video using an AVPlayerViewController and it runs with no issues on iOS 16.
I tried to run it on iOS 17 but it's not working.

When instantiating the VC with

```
let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
```

I am getting the error:
`-AVSystemController- +[AVSystemController sharedInstance]: Failed to allocate AVSystemController, numberOfAttempts=1`

And when setting

```
playerVC.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "myVideoURL")!)
```

I am getting this error: `<<<< Async >>>> playerasync_runAsynchronousCommandOnQueue: Command 26 returned -12,784; this async error will be discarded`

So far I couldn't find any reported issue with iOS 17 and AVKit.

Comment: I was running it with XCode 15, but I also tried with XCode 14 now and it works fine even on iOS 17, so apparently the problem is with XCode 15 (still in Beta)